# PowerBI_filter IDs exclusively contains a value in a column

Tags: filter, powerbi

I would like to select IDs exclusively have "sushi" in the table below:

```
ID   FOOD   CITY
ID1  sushi  ny
ID2  sushi  ny
ID3  sushi  sh
ID4  sushi  sh
ID5  sushi  pa
ID6  sushi  pa
ID3  noodle il
ID4  noodle il
ID5  noodle il
ID6  noodle il
```

expected result is:

```
ID   FOOD   CITY
ID1  sushi  ny
ID2  sushi  ny
```

May I ask how to create this type of filter in PowerBI? Thank you!

Comment: What is the logic for selecting ID1 and ID2 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the logic for getting your required output correct, you can create a measure as below and use that measure to Visual level filter to get your desired output-

**Measure:**

```
is_exclusive = 

VAR current_id = MIN(your_table_name[ID])

VAR id_wise_food_count = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[FOOD]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[ID] = current_id
    )
)

VAR id_wise_sushi_count = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[FOOD]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[ID] = current_id 
            && your_table_name[FOOD] = "sushi"
    )
)

RETURN IF(id_wise_food_count = id_wise_sushi_count, 1, 0)
```

**Here is the output of measure-**

[image]

**Now add the visual level filter using the measure as shown below-**

[image]

**Here below the final output**-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have tried as above, and applied to my big dataset. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Nice to see that it helped.